# Pass variable from view to view codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to know how to send variable from one view to another view in codeigniter.

MY controller 
I want to pass that "input" variable here:

```
public function registroArea()
    {
        $data = array('views' => 'registrarArea');
        $input = array();
        $input["input_name"]= array(
            'name' => 'nombreArea',
            'class' => 'form-control');
        $input["input_submit"]= array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'value' => 'Guardar',
            'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg');

        //print_r($input);

        $this->load->view('template', $data, $input);
    }
```

My template view from which I load another view:

```
<section class="content">
    <?php if($views==""): ?>
      <center>
       <h1>Bienvenido</h1>
      </center>
     <?php else:?>
     <?php $this->load->view($views, $input);?>
     <?php endif; ?>
    </section>
```

My view form in which you should load the variable in "input":

```
<?php echo form_open('GuardarArea') ?>
            </br></br>
             <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">                        
                    <?php echo form_label("nombre del area", "nombreArea") ?>
                        <div class="controls">
                        <?php echo form_input($input_name) ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3"></div>
              </div>  <!-- Div row -->
             </div>  <!-- Div container -->
             </br></br>
             <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">   
                    <center>
                     <?php echo form_submit($input_submit) ?>
                    </center>           
                </div> <!-- Div col-xs-12 col-md-12-->
                </div><!-- Div row-->
            </div> <!-- Div container -->
<?php echo form_close()?>
```

I thank you for your collaboration.

Comment: i think from your first view you should pass `$input_name` rather than `$input`, and then in your second view, `$input_name` will just be available as `$input_name`

Comment: If you mean this:

$inputname= array(
   'name' => 'nombreArea',
   'class' => 'form-control');
  $inputsubmit = array(
   'name' => 'submit',
   'value' => 'Guardar',
   'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg');
 
  $this->load->view('template', $data, $inputname,$inputsubmit);

I already tried. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the info through the data array, normally you should be able to access it in subsequent views that are being loaded.

EDIT: The 3th argument of the load->view should not be used to pass variables.
See documentation: [Codeigniter Views](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data)

As you should do is send the data from your controller through the data array:

```
$data['input'] = array(
        "input_name"    => array(
                            'name'  => 'nombreArea',
                            'class' => 'form-control'),
        "input_submit"  => array(
                            'name'  => 'submit',
                            'value' => 'Guardar',
                            'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg'),
    );
```

This can be accessed in (all) subsequent views as `$input['input_name']`

Or you can pass the sub arrays as individual `$data['input_name']` and `$data['input_submit']` if you preferer to access them from your view as `$input_name` and `$input_submit`.

The `$data` parameter array will be passed on.

Comment: I cant not, I already did the mentioned thing @coderoduor, I still have the error: message: undefined variable: inputname.

Comment: I don't think you got me right, the 3th argument in the load view function is not ment to pass variables! https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data

Comment: I understand, sorry I've been using it for a short time, but the problem itself is to carry a variable from the controller to that form view that passes through a template

Comment: The $data array is being passed to the view when loading the template.  Each key from that array is accessable as a variable from the view page.  If you load onother view, those should be accessible from within all subsequent views.   As you are using this to generate forms, there might be better ways to generate your forms element then defining each element in your controler, which gives you lot's of code, while it's better to maintain 'thin' controlers, but that's another discussion.